# Magento 2 - Add category to beginning of a sub menu (in Top Menu)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am trying to add a category menu node to the beginning of the category node tree created by the Magento plugin `Magento\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Topmenu`.

I have managed to add menu links to the menu using a custom class (plugin) that calls the same function `beforeGetHtml()` and adds a link to the relevant node using a specific parent node:
`$parentNode->addChild($categoryNode);` where `$parentNode` is an existing category node link.

The problem is that there is no way to add children to the front of the node collection. `Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node` does not offer such function.

Also you will notice that the function `moveNodeTo()` of `Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node` is not implemented:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Data/Tree.php#L111

Any idea?